# SVN to Git migration where SVN repository has repositories inside it

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have a Subversion repository with the following folder structure:

```
projectname
projectname/api
projectname/services/service1
projectname/services/service2
projectname/webapps/app1
projectname/webapps/app2
```

Using Subversion I can checkout all or individual repositories. I have converted the root repository to a git repository. Now I am not able to clone individual project e.g. `"projectname/webapps/app1"`.

Is there anything I missed during migration? Is there any git svn command that converts a Subversion repository to a Git repository and creates submodules from inner svn repositories?

Comment: In svn every directory can be treated as a repo. Git submodules are lame and inflexible in comparison to that.

Comment: Strictly speaking subdirectories of a Subversion repository are not repositories themselves.

Comment: agreed to @MichaWiedenmann

Comment: See here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50142471/4175515).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want transforme app1 in a git repo.
And app1 has the follow directory

trunk, branches, tags

```
git svn init --prefix=svn/ --username='user' --no-metadata --no-minimize-url --trunk='trunk' --tags='tags' --branches='branches' http://svnserver/projectname/webapps/app1
```

--trunk='trunk' --tags='tags' --branches='branches' do the trick to transform everything inside branches to git branches, trunk to master and tags folders to git tags.

--no-minimize-url will consider only http://svnserver/projectname/webapps/app1 and not http://svnserver/projectname/ (the root of your repo).

[Git svn docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn)

[svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git), nice tool to convert one to another.