# SVN to GitHub migration

Tags: github, svn, github-pages, git-svn, visualsvn

I have to migrate multiple directories from SVN trunk to **one** single GitHub repository.  I'm able to clone single directory at a time by using this command:

```
git svn clone "https://svn repo url"
```

How to clone multiple directories with a single command from svn trunk? What is the best way to do migration?

Comment: never done, but i think this is a good starting point... https://help.github.com/articles/source-code-migration-tools/

Answer (score 0):

In the hard way [officil svn to git migration](https://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git) you have to run a bunch of command to make the conversion, basically transforming trunk to master, svn revision's in commit's (git style) and svn tags (running git svn clone all tags are branches) to git tags.

The easy way [using this tool](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git), beware of a [bug](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/issues/242) if your svn repo is password protected.